# The difference between the Either and Both in English?

Tags: word-usage, difference

What's the difference between the Either and Both?

When and how should we use each of them?

Comment: Why do you want to close this question?

Comment: @SovereignSun Actually, I don't want to close the question. I'm new to this community and I'd like to know why the question is put on hold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Either** is used to speak only about one or the other of two elements; to select one out of two.
- **Both** is used to indicate the first and the second elements together.

Examples:

1. It was **either** James **or** Bobby who did it. *(Only one of them did it)*
2. It was **both** James **and** Bobby who did it. *(James and Bobby did it together)*

Notice that with "**either**" you use "**or**" and with "**both**" you use "**and**". Notice also, that it's natural to use "**either**" only with two options or elements.

- [*Cambridge Grammar - **Either***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/either)
- [*Cambridge Grammar - **Both***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/both)

Notice that Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary says that “**either**” can be used “*before two or more coordinate words, phrases, or clauses joined usually by or.*” and most dictionaries generally accept the use of “either” or “neither” to introduce a series of more than two items:

> - I called you up yesterday and you didn't answer. Where were you?
> - I was **either** *at the shop*, *the cinema*, *my dad's garage* **or** *at my girlfriend's home*. It all depends on when you called me up.

---

Another example:

- Do you want to go to Gabriel Kreuther or Per Se? **Both** *restaurants* **are** good.
- Do you want to go to Gabriel Kreuther or Per Se? **Either** *restaurant* **is** good.

Basically, both the sentences mean the same thing, however, when we use "**both**" we indicate that the first one is good and the second one is good. When we use "**either**" we indicate that each of them is good.

Comment: Another thing to note is that with more than two options in an "either or" statement, each word is only used once: "Would you like an ice cream? You can have **either** chocolate, strawberry, **or** vanilla."